# Error While Trying To Transform Data Into Stocks Object

Tags: r, rstudio

I am following a tutorial on R-Bloggers on an introduction to stock market data analysis. I got to this part -

```
if (!require("magrittr")) {
install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr)
}

## Loading required package: magrittr
stock_return % t % > % as.xts

head(stock_return)
```

But, I keep getting this error -

```
Error: unexpected '>' in "stock_return % t % >"
```

Please how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two versions of the tutorial. One version incomplete, the other complete. This is the complete version -

```
if (!require("magrittr")) {
    install.packages("magrittr")
    library(magrittr)
}

stock_return = apply(stocks, 1, function(x) {x / stocks[1,]}) %>% 
                                t %>% as.xts

head(stock_return)
```